# adding an order by to this query returns faster than without, why?

Tags: sql-server-2005, order-by

Any ideas on why adding a sort to this query returns considerably faster than without the order by? I would expect the opposite so what could make this happen?

```
SELECT TOP (500) r.cID,r.aField,a.Description 
       FROM dbo.tblR r  
            inner join dbo.tblA a on r.aID = a.ID  
            left join dbo.tblX x on x.cID = r.cID 
       WHERE (ISNULL(x.anotherField,'') <> r.anotherField or x.field3 is null) 
            and (r.ID=(select max(ID) from tblR where cID = r.cID and
            ISNULL(aField,'') <> '')) 
            and r.cID in (select ID from tblC)
       ORDER BY r.cID ASC -- when I comment this line out it runs much slower
```

The execution plans are not helping out much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious cause would be that `(select max(ID) from tblR where cID = c.cID and ISNULL(aField,'') <> '')` sub-query in the `WHERE` clause in combination with the `TOP 500` is making the order make a difference.

In either case it will probably be running that sub-query individually for every row it might otherwise return until it has found 500 that match the whole `WHERE` (actually, it will be bright enough to check the other parts of the WHERE first, as they are much less expensive, but still it will be running the sub-query for a portion of the rows it meets). At a guess, more rows near the top when sorted by c.cID match currently so it has to run the sub-query less often before finding 500 matches than it does when running down the results in the order the query planner chooses by default.

(I'm assuming that the `c`s should be `x`s or vice-versa, otherwise the query would not run as the alias `c` is not defined anywhere)

It is worth running queries like that in the Management Studio with the "actual query plan" view turned on - then you might see from the diagram which parts are causing the differeing performance.